# How to set private variable in java bean

Tags: java

```
I have a java bean class such as :
public class EncBean {
private String name;
private String ReversedBinary;
private String ConcatenatedData;

public String getReversedBinary() {
    return ReversedBinary;
}
public void setReversedBinary(String ReversedBinary) {
    this.ReversedBinary = ReversedBinary;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getConcatenatedData() {
    return ConcatenatedData;
}
public void setConcatenatedData(String name) {
    this.ConcatenatedData = ConcatenatedData;
}
 }
```

and I tried to set a value for the private java bean field(ConcatenatedData)   as follow :

```
public EncBean conctdat(){
    EncBean encBean4 = new EncBean();

encBean4.setConcatenatedData(inputkey.concat(var)); 
return  encBean4;
}
```

and in main i tried to access this value as:

```
mainenc concatdata =new mainenc();

   EncBean encbeandata = concatdata.conctdat();

   System.out.println("concatenated data is: "+encbeandata.getConcatenatedData());
```

but it gives me null

concatenated data is: null

Comment: and what is this: inputkey.concat(var) ?

Comment: String inputkey = in.nextLine(); and  var=encBean3.getName();

Comment: and what values does it contain?

Comment: i solved my problem very thanks for you

Comment: so what was the problem?

Comment: in this line  public void setConcatenatedData(String name) {
    this.ConcatenatedData = name;
} // it must be  this.ConcatenatedData = ConcatenatedData ;

Comment: ehm, no. if the parameter you pass is called name, in your assignment it should be name as well. maybe I missunderstand your explanation, though

Comment: parameter i pass is called ConcatenatedData  but i forget to modify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fix implementation of setConcatenatedData() to :

```
public void setConcatenatedData(String name) {

        this.ConcatenatedData = name; // instead of this.ConcatenatedData = ConcatenatedData

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one is:

```
public void setConcatenatedData(String name) {
    this.ConcatenatedData = name;
}
```

Second one, you should double check if `inputkey.concat(var)` is null.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by Getter & Setter.

This will help:

```
setConcatenatedData(String name) {   
     this.ConcatenatedData = name;
}
```

Comment: in main i set it ok? but in another class i tried to get this value it gives null